# I'm trying to train a model, but the loss keeps increasing or fluctuating

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to train a model, but the loss keeps increasing or fluctuating.

that is my model:

```
class u_seta(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim):
        super().__init__()

        self.block = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Linear(input_dim, 256),
                nn.PReLU(),
                nn.Linear(256, 512),
                nn.PReLU(),
                nn.Linear(512,256),
                nn.PReLU(),
                nn.Linear(256, output_dim)
            )

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.block(x)
        return out
```

I am using Adam Optimizer:

```
u_setaNet = utils.KRU_utils.u_seta(75,72).to(device)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(u_setaNet.parameters(),lr=1e-4)
```

Training section:

```
for now_step in range(n+1):
    if(now_step==0):
        q_i_est = data_3D_pose.clone().to(device)
        q_i_est.requires_grad = True
        
        X_est = utils.KRU_utils.pose_to_3d(q_i_est,data_3D).to(device)
        X_est.retain_grad()

        x_est = utils.KRU_utils.joint3d_to_2d(X_est,data_3D).to(device)
        Loss = utils.KRU_utils.LossF(x_est,data_2D_keypoint).to(device)
        Loss = Loss.sum(dim=1)

        Loss.backward(torch.ones(X_est.shape[0]).to(device)) 
        X_est = X_est.grad
        X_est = X_est.reshape(X_est.shape[0],-1).to(device)
        Loss = Loss.detach()
    
    else:
        
        q_i_est = q_i_est.detach()
        X_est = X_est.detach()
        X_est.requires_grad = True
    
        q_i_est_alter = u_setaNet(X_est)
        
        q_i_est = q_i_est + q_i_est_alter
    
        X_est_again = utils.KRU_utils.pose_to_3d(q_i_est,data_3D).to(device)
        x_est_again = utils.KRU_utils.joint3d_to_2d(X_est_again,data_3D).to(device)
    
        Loss = utils.KRU_utils.LossF(x_est_again,data_2D_keypoint).to(device)
        Loss = Loss.sum(dim=1)
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        Loss.backward(torch.ones(X_est.shape[0]).to(device))
        optimizer.step()

        X_est = X_est.grad
        X_est = X_est.reshape(X_est.shape[0],-1).to(device)
    
        loss_txt_cont += Loss.sum().item()
        Loss = Loss.detach()
        print(data_startP,data_endP,Loss.sum())
```

The loss function is:

```
def LossF(joint2d,data_2D_keypoint):
    Loss = joint2d[:,:,0:2] - data_2D_keypoint[:,:,0:2]
    Loss = torch.sqrt(Loss[:,:,0]** 2 +  Loss[:,:,1]** 2)
    Loss = (Loss*data_2D_keypoint[:,:,2])
    return Loss
```

The following are the losses at different learning rates:

```
lr=1e-3

0 1 tensor(2325.0229, device=‘cuda:0’)
0 1 tensor(2532.3550, device=‘cuda:0’)
0 1 tensor(2623.1548, device=‘cuda:0’)
0 1 tensor(2475.8281, device=‘cuda:0’)
0 1 tensor(2532.1895, device=‘cuda:0’)
0 1 tensor(2526.4036, device=‘cuda:0’)

lr=1e-4

0 1 tensor(2150.0894, device=‘cuda:0’)
0 1 tensor(2583.2695, device=‘cuda:0’)
0 1 tensor(2855.8999, device=‘cuda:0’)
0 1 tensor(2928.6746, device=‘cuda:0’)
0 1 tensor(3010.9243, device=‘cuda:0’)
0 1 tensor(3128.9155, device=‘cuda:0’)
```

I need to input ∂loss/∂X_est to the network and then get the output of the network, i.e. the amount of adjustment of q_i_est that maps out X_est. After that, through a series of changes, the value obtained by the transformation is compared with the target to get the loss. Since it is not possible to directly compare the loss of the network output with the target, I want to optimize only the network and not the transformations.
A series of transformations are performed after the network output, will this cause anomalies in the training?

[The magnitude of the value during the transformation](https://i.postimg.cc/Jn84Hh3G/e4352a01c4f820a883160f312849be5a9c990b15-2-1380x328.png)

How should I modify it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'd focus on the optimizer both trying different values for lr and perhaps different optimizer algorithms as well. Perhaps try `SGD`.

Have you tried running it with default lr? `optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(u_setaNet.parameters())`
Try some grid search for lr if this didn't work, e.g. `lr=(1e-5, 5e-5, 1e-4, 5e-4, 1e-3, 5e-3, 1e-2, 5e-2, 1e-1)`, to see if any of those values happen to make the loss converge.

The other question is how much training data do you have?

Comment: I try to use the adam optimizer with default learning rate(lr=0.001). 
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(u_setaNet.parameters())  
The change in loss is:   2081.3115 -> 2182.8015 -> 2615.3208-> 2152.3120 -> 2385.1350-> 2186.0337

Comment: I tried using the SGD optimizer(lr=1e-7).
The change in loss is: 2734.0955 -> 2977.9561 -> 3150.6475-> 3270.2666 -> 3355.6106 -> 3444.7905 .

and I tried using the SGD optimizer(lr=1e-15).
loss : 1833.9480 -> 2310.1196 -> 2799.0581-> 3082.2397 -> 3213.2300 -> 3317.3416.

Comment: These are the results when the training has just started, I think the loss should decrease at each training when the learning rate is very small.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should specify a little more the problem you are facing, because it would be easier to detect the fault.

For example, in your code you can see that after the layer of
`nn.Linear(256, output_dim)` you don't have any activation function, so without knowing what kind of problem you are facing I don't know if this is a good decision.

Comment: The problem I encountered was that the loss of the network during training did not decrease. This network u is only for the output of how I should adjust the input to the network (to be precise the input is a mapping of the values being adjusted).

Comment: That is, the value I need maps an intermediate value before performing the offset, and the derivative of the intermediate value is input to the network. The network gives an offset value, adds the offset value to the original value, how to map a second intermediate value, the second intermediate value and my truth-ground to calculate the loss. Finally use this loss to optimize the network.